# Забавний чи кумедний

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

Є таке речення: "Кожен батько з цікавістю спостерігає за тим, як його дитина прагне бути самостійною, як вона робить свої перші кроки, а також *забавні* спроби донести ложку до рота не втративши дорогою їжу."
Питання полягає в правильності вживання слова "забавний". Сервіс перевірки україномовних текстів підкреслює вжите слово "забавний" як помилку, пропонуючи натомісць "кумедний, потішний, смішний, цікавий"
Але в Російсько-українському академічному словнику А. Кримського є така стаття:

> Заба́вный – 
>   1) (приятно забавл.) уті́шний, уті́шливий, поті́шний, заба́вний. [Така́ та́я дити́нка вті́шна була́, ще я тако́ї втішне́нької і не ба́чила. Таке́ га́рне, уті́шливе хлоп’я́. Яко́го пісе́нь сла́вних вона́ співа́ла, яко́го казочо́к поті́шних умі́ла! (М. Вовч.)]; 
>   2) (смешной) куме́дний, весе́лий, ціка́вий. [Куме́дне таке́ кошеня́тко. Куме́дна по́милка. Наби́в собі́ на ло́бі таку́ ціка́ву ґу́лю, що не мо́жна було́ не регота́тися]. 
>   • -ный человек – куме́дна люди́на. 
>   • -ные приключения – весе́лі приго́ди.

Тож яке слово вжити буде доречним?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Відразу дам відповідь, а потім поясню детальніше: загалом слово "забавний" використовувати можна, але треба також не забувати про решту згаданих слів, бо вони є прямішими відповідниками російському "заба́вный".

Спочатку ваше цитування Кримського:

> Заба́вный – 1) (приятно забавл.) уті́шний, уті́шливий, поті́шний,
>   заба́вний.

Бачимо, що "забавний" у ряді перекладів стоїть на останньому місці. У тому ж словнику знаходимо інший переклад:

> • Требующий, отнимающий много времени – забарни́й, зага́йний, ба́вний,
>   забавни́й.

Тобто, це слово використовувалось у ще одному значенні.

Підтвердження такого застосування слова бачимо й у [Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> • Требующий, отнимающий много времени – (про роботу тощо) Забарний;
>   загайний; (лок.) забавний (бавний).

Схоже значення знаходимо у [Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> Забавни́й – медлительный.

Так само у [Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9):

> Забавни́й, а́, е́. = Забарний.
>   [Забарни́й](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), а́, е́  1) Медлительный.

Однак, бачимо також два словника ([Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) і [Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)), які подають "забавний" як "увеселительный", тобто, такий, що стосується "увеселений" або "забав", що вже ближче до того значення, яке було у реченні, де батько слідкує за дитиною, але далеко не повністю відповідає потрібному значенню.

Отже, мусимо мати на увазі, що до радянської доби основна частина словників надавала перевагу іншому значенню слова "забавний", з наголосом на останньому складі, а навіть значення слова "увеселительный" не є тотожним значенню слова "забавний", тож краще користуватися прикметником "забавний" з пересторогою.

Comment: У тому ж словнику знаходимо інший переклад:

• Требующий, отнимающий много времени – забарни́й, зага́йний, ба́вний, забавни́й. (а також інші словники за наведеним значенням) - тут маємо орфоепічний омонім: наголос припадає на закінчення, тому і значення різниться.

Comment: Наскільки я знаӱ, ‚забаўниь‘ на Заходї то переважно для позначеннь [‚гра‘](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53399/1062424.html) була, або про [‚піклування‘](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53399/1062426.html). Польська теж має цюго [слова](//sjp.pl/zabawa). Тому слово словʼянське, але, так, як пан правильно зазначиў, наразї взляло здебільшено московського значення ‚кумедниь‘.

Comment: @OksanaÇeliker так, але навіть "увеселительньій" - це зовсім не "забавньій", тож маємо лише словник Кримського+Єфремова, що не є достатньо, як на мене. До того ж, я так і сказав, що користуватися можна, але просто не забувати про синоніми + не зловживати. + ТРОХИ ВІДРЕДАҐУВАВ ВІДПОВІДЬ.

Comment: @Follower вас стає все складніше розуміти. Наражаєтесь на небезпеку, що вас просто перестануть сприймати через спосіб написання літер.

Comment: @P.Vovk, а я навпаки вже почав звикати (хоча початкова реакція була як у Вас).